# Adding 2 input values on keyup to get the answer in the 3rd input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

i know this has been asked before but i can't seem to get this right. I need to take input values from two text boxes and add it to another and that answer should appear in the 3rd textbox after both boxes are typed in. Nothing seems to be happening however though. Thanks

Here's the HTML

```
 //Input 1 
  <input name="attribute_campaign_addon_one_time_cost_value" id="am_attribute_campaign_addon_one_time_cost_value">

 //Input 2 
 <input name="attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_value" id="attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_value">

//Input 3 where added answer should go
 <input name="attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_calculated_value" id="am_attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_calculated_value" value=""> 

 //JQ
  var $oneTimeCostField = $('#am_attribute_campaign_addon_one_time_cost_value');
  var $recurringTotalCostField = $('#am_attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_value');
  var $totalRetailAmountField = $('#am_attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_calculated_value');

  function calcVal() {
        var num1 = $oneTimeCostField.val();
        var num2 = $recurringTotalCostField.val();
        var result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            $totalRetailAmountField.val() = result;
        }
    }

 calcVal();
  $(num1, num2).on("keydown keyup", function() {
    calcVal();
});
```

Comment: `num1` and `num2` are *values*. They don't raise `keyup` events. Bind your listener to the actual input fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector for the onkeyup/down is wrong, and your total field has the wrong id.
The result can be set like this: `$totalRetailAmountField.val(result);`

```js
 //JQ
  var $oneTimeCostField = $('#am_attribute_campaign_addon_one_time_cost_value');
  var $recurringTotalCostField = $('#am_attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_value');
  var $totalRetailAmountField = $('#am_attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_calculated_value');

  function calcVal() {
    
        var num1 = $oneTimeCostField.val();
        var num2 = $recurringTotalCostField.val();
        var result = parseInt(num1, 10) + parseInt(num2, 10);
        console.log("calcVal ", num1,num2, result);
        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            $totalRetailAmountField.val(result);
        }
    }

 calcVal();
  $oneTimeCostField.on("keydown keyup", function() {
    calcVal();
  });
  $recurringTotalCostField.on("keydown keyup", function() {
    calcVal();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
//Input 1 
  <input name="attribute_campaign_addon_one_time_cost_value" id="am_attribute_campaign_addon_one_time_cost_value">

 //Input 2 
 <input name="attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_value" id="am_attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_value">

//Input 3 where added answer should go
 <input name="attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_calculated_value" id="am_attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_calculated_value" value="">
```

Comment: Can i ask, what if the retail amount is say input1 is 11.57 and input2 is 45.78? - it's just rounding off.

Comment: You can use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to make it understand the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Jquery input value is set as follows:

```
   $totalRetailAmountField.val(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing, I have never seen `name` & `id` such big value. this is not only cause problem in readability but also introduce error like unwanted space in id

Secondly `num1` & `num2` are already jquery object then what is the use of `$(num1, num2)`

Thirdly update the value of the third input by passing the vale as function argument `$totalRetailAmountField.val(result);`

```js
var $oneTimeCostField = $('#am_attribute_campaign_addon_one_time_cost_value');
var $recurringTotalCostField = $('#attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_value');
var $totalRetailAmountField = $('#am_attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_calculated_value');

function calcVal() {
  var num1 = $oneTimeCostField.val();
  var num2 = $recurringTotalCostField.val();
  var result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    $totalRetailAmountField.val(result);
  }
}


$('#attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_value,#am_attribute_campaign_addon_one_time_cost_value').on("keydown keyup", function() {

  calcVal();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="attribute_campaign_addon_one_time_cost_value" id="am_attribute_campaign_addon_one_time_cost_value">

<input name="attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_value" id="attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_value">

<input name="attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_calculated_value" id="am_attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_calculated_value" value=" ">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly verbose solution to your query. 
Listen to change on each input and apply their respective values to the final answer input (`input#fa`)

```js
const a1 = document.querySelector('#a1')
const a2 = document.querySelector('#a2')
const fa = document.querySelector('#fa')
const answers = []

const _handleFinalAnswer = () => (fa.value = (+answers[0] || 0) + (+answers[1] || 0))

a1.addEventListener('change', e => {
  const { value } = e.target
  answers[0] = value
  
  _handleFinalAnswer()
})

a2.addEventListener('change', e => {
  const { value } = e.target
  answers[1] = value

  _handleFinalAnswer()
})
```

```html
<input type="number" step="any" name="answer 1" id="a1" />
<input type="number" step="any" name="answer 2" id="a2" />

<input name="final answer" id="fa" />
```

Or here is a more dynamic way to calculate all possible amount of inputs to achieve a final sum but it could still be done with two inputs :-)

```js
const answersInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input.answer')
const finalAnswer = document.querySelector('#fa')

const _getSummedValues = () => (
  [...answersInputs]
  .map(input => +input.value || 0)
  .reduce((prev, curr) => prev+curr, 0)
)

const _setFinal = () => finalAnswer.value = _getSummedValues()

answersInputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', _setFinal))
```

```html
<input type="number" step="any" name="answer 1" class="answer" />
<input type="number" step="any" name="answer 2" class="answer" />
<input type="number" step="any" name="answer 3" class="answer" />
<input type="number" step="any" name="answer 4" class="answer" />
<input type="number" step="any" name="answer 5" class="answer" />
<input type="number" step="any" name="answer 6" class="answer" />
<input type="number" step="any" name="answer 7" class="answer" />


<input name="final answer" id="fa" />
```

Comment: Wow that's awesome :). Way beyond my knowledge haha

Comment: @erics15 did you find your solution from our Answers? If so, go with whatever one is more readable to you.

Comment: thank you, yes I accepted the answer. Yours is amazing, I just need to learn a little more of that syntax to fully understand it.

Comment: No problem glad you got a solution. It may be worth looking at `querySelectors`. it's satisfying taking some JQuery code and making it vanilla.